# Why does the CRC of "1" yield the generator polynomial itself?

Tags: algorithm, crc, calculation, crc16

While testing a CRC implementation, I noticed that the CRC of 0x01 usually (?) seems to be the polynomial itself. When trying to manually do the binary long division however, I keep ending up losing the leading "1" of the polynomial, e.g. with a message of "0x01" and the polynomial "0x1021", I would get

```
      1 0000 0000 0000 (zero padded value)
(XOR) 1 0000 0010 0001
-----------------
      0 0000 0010 0001 = 0x0021
```

But any sample implementation (I'm dealing with XMODEM-CRC here) results in 0x1021 for the given input.

Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks, I can see how the XOR step of the upper bit leaving the shift register with the generator polynomial will cause this result. What I *don't* get is why this step is performed in that manner at all, seeing as it clearly alters the result of a true polynomial division?

Comment: You are forgetting that the polynomial also has an implicit 1 bit, just to the left of the bit width.  You should actually be calculating with `1 0001 0000 0010 0001`.

Comment: I just noticed that too, see my post below.. Is there a place that might have made this more obvious? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Designing_polynomials lists every CRC-n with a length of n+1 and I now understand why, but there's no explicit mention of the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt and noticed that in section 9, there is mention of an implicitly prepended 1 to enforce the desired polynomial width.

In my example case, this means that the *actual* polynomial used as divisor would not be 0x1021, but 0x11021. This results in the leading "1" being dropped, and the remainder being the "intended" 16-bit polynomial:

```
      1 0000 0000 0000 0000 (zero padded value)
(XOR) 1 0001 0000 0010 0001
-----------------
      0 0001 0000 0010 0001 = 0x1021
```

Comment: In this case the CRC polynomial is 0x11021. It is possible to implement this using 16 bit math, and ignoring the most significant bit of the CRC polynomial, but this could also be done using 32 bit math and not ignoring the most significant bit of the polynomial. The inner loop would be something like `... crc <<= 1;` , `if(crc & 0x10000) crc ^= 0x11021` .